# Get contents from second iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I can retrieve the contents of the first iframe on a web page that is not mine with `$('iframe').contents()`

From this I can get the body tag by doing `$('iframe').contents().find('body')`. The results are what is expected

However, I an trying to get the body tag of the second iframe. By doing `$('iframe').eq(1) I can get the second iframe, but $('iframe').eq(1).contents() gets nothing.

How can I get the contents of the second iframe?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the Fiddles and such may not be a good test place. There are complications with CORS. Here is an example that works:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/037yueqj/9/

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="frame-1"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame-2"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var f1 = $("#frame-1"),
    f2 = $("#frame-2"),
    frames = $("iframe");
  f1.contents().find("body").html("<strong>Frame 1</strong>");
  f2.contents().find("body").html("<strong>Frame 2</strong>");
  console.log(frames.eq(0).contents().find("body").text());
  console.log(frames.eq(1).contents().find("body").text());
});
```

If you give them unique IDs or classes, you can just call on the proper selector. You can call on a wider selector and use `.eq()` or iterate with `.each()`.

Comment: "At the moment I can retrieve the contents of the first iframe on a web page that is not mine" the web page is not mine, can't simply add a class or id

Comment: @MikeJohnson that raises big red flags. Is this for a Plugin? Please clarify things a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use --disable-web-security in chromium to access contents in an iframe from another url